# A good practise to seperate admin content from user content in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Working on a Laravel project to learn the framework. I just want some opinions/discussion on how to seperate for example an admin menu and admin content from a regular users content. Since Im new to the framework i do not know if my way is a good way to do this, maybe there is a better practise.

Right now i do checks in `routes.php` with before filters so unauthorized people not can access admin content.

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'superAdmin'), function()
{
    Route::get('/admin_start', array(
        'as' => 'admin_start',
        'uses' => 'HomeController@getAdminStart'
    ));
});
```

I have a `main.blade.php` layout file that determine if admin or the user menu should be shown.

```
<body>
    @if(Auth::check())
        @if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Superadmin'))
            @include('layout.navigationadmin')
        @else
            @include('layout.navigationuser')           
        @endif
    @endif
    @yield('content')
</body>
```

Is this a good/safe approach?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how structurally different the admin content and the visitor (non-authenticated) content are, and also how strictly you want to enforce your separation of concern.

**Admin Page/View is really different from non-authenticated user's view**

I would start with different base layout (your blade layout where you extend from). Note that this doesn't mean that they are totally separate from each other, you can always include the same fragments/partial blade view where they are commonly shared.

**They are different in some panels/sub-components/etc., but otherwise they look a lot like each other**

Can share the same layout, but try to re-use as many chunk of sub-views as possible. You'll know at some point when you have too many if/else statement just to include different templates; it'll probably be a good idea to rethink option 1. And if you are modularising your blade templates, it easy to do switch.

In your case, if the nav is really the only thing that differentiate admin and normal user, feel free to go for option 2. Otherwise probably option 1. Just my two cents.

Comment: I think you have a good point. For my application option 2 would be best i think. An admin should be able to create users, handle accounts etc from a menu, but otherwise from that the views and content should look about the same. However is it a good/safe approach to determine these important admin functions through a blade template?

Answer (score 0):

It will work, but I wouldn't say best practice. Laravel has filters for these things, here is a good resource to build one with a login: http://culttt.com/2013/09/16/use-laravel-4-filters/

Comment: Im using filters in groups just like the article you linked to. I guess the part that im unsure about is the role check etc in my main.blade.php layout

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoint is protected in your code above, but if you're looking for a better way to add menu items based on user role, id recommend view composers to bind certain data to your views.

Something like:

**Composers.php:** Add the file `app/composers.php`, include it in `app/start/global.php`, and put this in it.

```
View::composer(['layouts.master'], function($view){

    if(Auth::check()){
        $authClass = 'logged-in';

        $items = MenuMaker::getInternalItems();

        if(Auth::user()->hasRole('Superadmin'))
            $items = array_merge($items, [ 'your admin items' ])

    } else {
        $items  = MenuMaker::getPublicItems();

        $authClass = 'logged-out';

        $view->with('mainNav', View::make('components.mainNavPublic', ['items' => $items]))
                ->with('authClass', $authClass);

    }

});
```

**View:**

```
<body class="{{ $authClass }}">
    {{ $mainNav }}
    @yield('content')
</body>
```